# Why is pandas read_csv not reading the right number of rows?

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I'm trying to open part of a csv file using pandas read_csv. The section I am opening has a header on line 746, and goes to line 1120.

```
 gr = read_csv(inputfile,header=746,nrows=374,index_col=False)
```

I then get an error

```
CParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 9 fields in line 1121, saw 17
```

The error makes sense, because in line 1121 of the file, the data changes from 9 fields to 17. What doesn't make sense is why it is trying to read line 1121, as the nrows and header should only open lines up to 1120.

I can get it to work by decreasing the number of rows to below 232. This still works even if I increase the header number so it starts further down the file (eg increase it to 800).

There doesn't seem to be anything special about the last line it will read, and it will read lines further in the file if I increase the header number.

I am using Python 2.7 and pandas 0.14.

The file I am trying to read looks like:

```
"River Levels","GRETA_SOUTH      (C)","GLENROWAN        (C)","ROCKY_POINT      (C)","DOCKER_RD        (C)","BOBINAWARRAH     (C)","WOOLSHED         (C)","WANGARATTA       (C)","PEECHELBA_EAST   (C)"
 41812.00001,          0.70,          0.00,          0.00,          0.20,          0.00,          0.00,          7.30,        125.00
 41812.04168,          0.70,          0.00,          0.00,          0.20,          0.00,          0.00,          7.30,        125.00
```

Why is it trying to open line 1121, when nrows+header is less than this, and why will it only read 232 lines before it does this?

Comment: Also RIVER LEVELS! A topic close to my own heart!! (I can't +1 again!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless I'm reading the docs wrong this looks like a bug in `read_csv` (I recommend filling an issue on github!).

A workaround, since your data is smallish (read in the lines as a string):

```
from StringIO import StringIO
with open(inputfile) as f:
    df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(''.join(f.readlines()[:1120])), header=746, nrows=374)
```

*I tested this with the csv you provide and it works/doesn't raise!*

Comment: Thanks that worked. I'll raise this as an issue on github as well.

Comment: @ChrisLeahy: Did you file it on GitHub?   This issue seems to still exist two years later in Pandas 0.19!

Comment: For anyone who is still running into this, it was a bug and should be fixed in 0.19.2. Using engine='python' is the best workaround until then.

Answer (score 0):

I reckon this is an off by one/counting (user) error! That is, `pd.read_csv(inputfile, header=746, nrows=374)` reads the 1021st **1-indexed** line, so you should read one fewer row. I could be mistaken, but here's what I'm thinking...

---

In python line indexing (as with most python indexing) starts at 0.

```
In [11]: s = 'a,b\nA,B\n1,2\n3,4\n1,2,3,4'

In [12]: for i, line in enumerate(s.splitlines()): print(i, line)
0 a,b
1 A,B
2 1,2
3 3,4
4 1,2,3,4
```

The *usual* way you think of line numbers is from 1:

```
In [12]: for i, line in enumerate(s.splitlines(), start=1): print(i, line)
1 a,b
2 A,B
3 1,2
4 3,4
5 1,2,3,4
```

In the following we are reading up the the 3rd row (with python indexing) or the 4th (with 1-indexing):

```
In [13]: pd.read_csv(StringIO(s), header=1, nrows=2)  # Note: header + nrows == 3
Out[13]:
   A  B
0  1  2
1  3  4
```

And if we include the next line it'll raise:

```
In [15]: pd.read_csv(StringIO(s), header=1, nrows=3)
CParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 2 fields in line 5, saw 4
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm enough of a newbie to make that error, but I don't think that is what's going on in this case. If it was, changing the number of rows from 374 to 373, should fix it, but I need to change it to something much less for it to work.

Comment: What do you need to change it to? Perhaps there is another dud row?

Comment: 231 is the highest I can go. The weird part is that if I increase the head line (for example to 800), it still works as long as I don't increase the number of lines past 231.

Comment: Can you link to this dataset, this sounds bizarre, may also be worth posting as a github issue!