# Pandas: read_csv() with engine=C issue (bug or feature?)

Tags: csv, pandas

I am using pandas 0.18 on python 2.7.9 on Suse Enterprise Linux 11.

I have a file that contains multiple tables:

```
TABLE_A
col1,col2,...,col8
...


TABLE_B
col1,col2,...,col7
...
```

Table A is about 7300 lines, and Table B is about 100 lines. I make an initial pass through the file to determine the start/end positions of each table. Then, I use read_csv() in pandas w/ skiprows, nrows options to read the appropriate table into memory. I'm using engine='c'.

I'm seeing weird behavior when using **engine='c'**. I'm able to read the first 4552 or so lines of TABLE_A without any issues. But If I try to read 4553 lines, I get an error:

```
>>> df = pd.read_csv(f,engine='c',skiprows=1,nrows=4552)
>>> df.shape
(4552, 7)

>>> df = pd.read_csv(f,engine='c',skiprows=1,nrows=4553)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/python_pkgs/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas-0.18.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 529, in parser_f
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
  File "/python_pkgs/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas-0.18.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 301, in _read
    return parser.read(nrows)
  File "/python_pkgs/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas-0.18.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 763, in read
    ret = self._engine.read(nrows)
  File "/python_pkgs/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas-0.18.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 1213, in read
    data = self._reader.read(nrows)
  File "pandas/parser.pyx", line 766, in pandas.parser.TextReader.read (pandas/parser.c:7988)
  File "pandas/parser.pyx", line 800, in pandas.parser.TextReader._read_low_memory (pandas/parser.c:8444)
  File "pandas/parser.pyx", line 842, in pandas.parser.TextReader._read_rows (pandas/parser.c:8970)
  File "pandas/parser.pyx", line 829, in pandas.parser.TextReader._tokenize_rows (pandas/parser.c:8838)
  File "pandas/parser.pyx", line 1833, in pandas.parser.raise_parser_error (pandas/parser.c:22649)
pandas.parser.CParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 7 fields in line 7421, saw 8
```

From the error message it seems like the C parser has continued reading way past the specified lines and has encountered TABLE_B which has 7 columns only (TABLE_A has 8 columns).

However, read with **engine='python'** works OK.

```
>>> df = pd.read_csv(f,engine='python',skiprows=1,nrows=6000)
>>> df.shape
(6000, 7)
>>>
```

So is this a bug or a feature/limitation? Perhaps maybe the way C parser works by reading chunks? Thanks.

Comment: What's line 4553 (and one or two lines before and after)? Often when I've encountered that error it was dirty data. Keep in mind this could be something very subtle like a smart quote, carriage return, or most commonly an extra comma.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is pandas read\_csv not reading the right number of rows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25985817/why-is-pandas-read-csv-not-reading-the-right-number-of-rows)

Comment: Yes this is a bug.  Still present in Pandas 0.19.